# Git not recognizing correct email for push to heroku

Tags: git, heroku, config

When running

```
git config --global user.email
```

I get the right email, but upon pushing to heroku it tells me that I can't push to heroku without the correct access rights, and returns a different email.

Answer (score 0):

The email from your config is used while you are committing. Hence when you see log it will show you correct email.

However while pushing to a remote typically push to the URL!
Check the user by which you are pushing! (`git remote -v` will tell you that)